# Generate request for Nominex using HMAC384

Tags: c#, rest, sha256, hmac

I am trying to authenticate to the Nominex API, I cannot find any C# examples of this request to Nominex. Documentation only has node.js example. I'm trying to convert it to C# but not having much luck, not sure what I'm doing wrong. The result I get is invalid credentials

Example in JavaScript

```
const crypto = require('crypto')
const request = require('request')

const apiKey = '...'
const apiSecret = '...'

const apiPath = '/api/rest/v1/private/wallets'
const nonce = Date.now().toString()
const queryParams = ''
const body = undefined
let signature = `/api${apiPath}${nonce}${body ? JSON.stringify(body) : ''}`

const sig = crypto.createHmac('sha384', apiSecret).update(signature)
const shex = sig.digest('hex')

const options = {
url: `https://nominex.io/${apiPath}?${queryParams}`,
headers: {
  'nominex-nonce': nonce,
  'nominex-apikey': apiKey,
  'nominex-signature': shex
},
  body: body,
  json: true
}
request.get(options, (error, response, body) => {
  console.log(body);
})
```

My attempt in C#

```
 private async Task<string> GetRequest()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string secretKey = apiSecret;
        TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
        long nonce = (long)t.TotalMilliseconds;

        string body = "";

        string requestPath = "/api/rest/v1/private/orders/BTC/USDT";
        string prehashString = string.Join("", requestPath, nonce.ToString(), body);

        string digest = "";

        using (var hmacsha384 = new HMACSHA384(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(secretKey)))
        {
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacsha384.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(prehashString));
            bool upperCase = false;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(hashmessage.Length * 2);
            for (int i = 0; i < hashmessage.Length; i++)
                result.Append(hashmessage[i].ToString(upperCase ? "X2" : "x2"));
            digest = result.ToString();                
        }

       

        HttpRequestMessage msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{baseUrl}{requestPath}");
        msg.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("nominex-apikey", apiKey);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("nominex-nonce",nonce.ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("nominex-signature", digest);

        var response = await client.SendAsync(msg);
        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return responseString;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `Encoding.Default`. I think the default encoding of `crypto` is utf8, so `Encoding.UTF8`

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha384?view=net-5.0

Comment: @xanatos I changed to UTF-8.. no difference

Comment: @jdweng - That link is signing a file stream, im trying to sign a request

Comment: Don't you have to add the Content Length to the request? client.ContentLength

Comment: @jdweng there isnt any actual content, just request headers.. the body is blank, its a get request vs Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature is:

```
let signature = `/api${apiPath}${nonce}${body ? JSON.stringify(body) : ''}`
```

so they add a `/api` **before** the `apiPath` that in the nodejs example is `/api/rest/v1/private/wallets`, so in that case the signature would be (with a `nonce` of `1609874861073`):

```
/api/api/rest/v1/private/wallets1609874861073
```

so

```
string prehashString = string.Concat("/api", requestPath, nonce.ToString(), body);
```

And replace all the `Encoding.Default` to `Encoding.UTF8`. They shouldn't give you any problem, but something wrong is something wrong.

Next time, if you have a nodejs installation on your pc, you can try their code on your nodejs, adding freely some console.log, otherwise there is a site, [repl.it](https://repl.it/), where you can try some node.js code (that is what I did to solve your problem).

Comment: thought the double /api was a typo.. seems to work now.. thanks!